# Undefined variable in view when testing Laravel controller

Tags: php, testing, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm trying to test some of the actions on my controller in Laravel 4 with PHPUnit.

```
public function testAboutPage()
{
    $this->client->request('GET', 'about');

    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

Also, I bind a variable to my views in the `App::before()` filter.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    View::share('usersCount', User::remember(60)->count());
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
class PagesController extends BaseController
{
    public function about()
    {
        return View::make('pages.about')->withTitle("About");
    }
}
```

However, my tests fail before the variable is not defined in testing. Here is the failing output from PHPUnit.

```
12) PagesControllerTest::testAboutPage
ErrorException: Undefined variable: usersCount (View: app/views/layouts/application.blade.php) (View: app/views/layouts/application.blade.php)

app/storage/views/ed261635437f52c903a09b2774ce5a92:20
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php:41
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php:56
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:134
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:102
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:76
app/storage/views/5993084368b648c9a244ec6637315755:18
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php:37
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php:56
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:134
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:102
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php:76
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php:70
vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php:202
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1413
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1003
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:968
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:738
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:708
vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:319
app/tests/controllers/PagesControllerTest.php:109
```

What can I do to resolve this issue? The variable is fine when viewing in a browser or in production.

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Added my controller code. As you can see, it's pretty simple.

Comment: Your error is in the `testUnsubscribedPage` method, but you only posted the code for the `testAboutPage` method.

Comment: Apologies, this issue affects all my tests on the PagesController. I switched my example from `testUnsubscribedPage` to `testAboutPage` as the controller action for it is dead simple.

Comment: Something's amiss. Your views shouldn't be called at all.

Comment: Would `$this->client->request('GET', 'about');` not render my views for the purpose of testing?

Comment: Nope. It calls your controller method, which returns the view object, but it doesn't call the render method on it, so the view is never processed.

Comment: @JosephSilber How do I test base controllers then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, it turns out that filters are disabled. I thought this just meant filters defined in the routes file, but it impacts app before/after filters also.

> Note: Route filters are disabled when in the testing environment. To enable them, add Route::enableFilters() to your test.

I've added this to my tests to make them go green.

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    Route::enableFilters();
}
```